# UK student visa

Tags: visa, student-visa

Back in 2009, I got a student visa refusal from Home Office due to the reason of me lacking of the fund to continue studying. Therefore after the first appeal, I decided to not to continue and left the UK back to Malaysia.

In 2015 I visited the UK and I had no issue coming in at the airport and they granted me a visiting visa.

Earlier this year I have been offered a place to study MA degree and my CAS has now been issued for this September 19 intake.

My question is should I disclose the visa refusal previously in my visa application.

I do have enough evidence available this time around to show 28 days money in my account financially to study and live in London this year.

Will there be any problem arise in my application this time around.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is should I disclose the visa refusal previously in my visa application.

Yes, obviously! It's not as if they won't know that they refused your last visa application if you don't tell them. If you answer no, then they will know that you are lying, your visa will be refused, and you will be banned from the UK for 10 years.

Comment: Thank you for the info and the clarification. I will tell them the truth.